# How to decompress RLE in C#?

Tags: c#, run-length-encoding

So basically I want to input something such as "05A03R02B" and for the program to return "AAAAARRRBB".

I'm relatively new to coding and it's a task I've been set so I have really no idea how to do it and haven't known what to try.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: REF - https://gist.github.com/sujaykundu777/9ee3328bf15fcc2b41a3576cf08b996c

Answer (score -1):

This snipped does your job:

```
private byte blockLength = 3;
private byte numLength = 2;

private void StringWorker(string input, out string output)
{
   var len = input.Length;

   if(len%blockLength!=0)
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("len has to be a multiple of blockLength");
   }

   var keys = new char[len/blockLength];
   var values = new byte[len/blockLength];
   var buffer = input.SubString(0,blockLength); //fill 1st block
   //parse string into keys and values
   for (var i = blockLength+1; i < s.Length; i++)
   {
      int index = i/blockLength;
      //check for new block
      if((i-1)%blockLength==0)
      {
         //assign values
         values[index] = Int32.Parse(buffer.SubString(i-blockLength-1,numLength);
         keys[index] = buffer[i-1];
         //clear buffer
         buffer="";
      }
      //add new char to buffer
      buffer+=input[i];
   }

   //compose new string from keys and values
   var sb = enw StringBuilder();
   for(var i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
   {
      var value = values[i];
      var key = keys[i];
      for(var j = 0; j < value; j++)
      {
         sb.Append(key);
      }
   }

   output = sb.ToString();
}
```